# how do I delete rows in Yii?

Tags: yii, delete-row

Using Yii, I want to delete all the rows that are not from today.

Is my solution ok ?

```
$query = "delete from `user_login_hash` where `day`!='".(date('Y-m-d',time()))."'";

Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A prettier solution is

```
YourUserModel::model()->deleteAll("day !='" . date('Y-m-d') . "'");
```

Comment: I have always found that using deleteAll works slower in comparison to DAO

Comment: +1 for the Model based delete, but a better way is to parameterize the condition:  YourUserModel::model()->deleteAll("day != :date", array('date' => date('Y-m-d')));  You also don't need the time(), since that is implicit.

Comment: I prefer to use it this way if I trust the data; also I copied the parameter list from the question, I did not want to confuse :)

Comment: you dont need model instance: YourUserModel::deleteAll("day != :date", array('date' => date('Y-m-d')));

Answer (score 12):

Better user PDO parameters and on command you also have to call `execute`

```php
$query = "delete from `user_login_hash` where `day`<> :date";
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
$command->execute(array('date' => date('Y-m-d')));
```

or

```php
UserLoginHash::model()->deleteAll(
    'day <> :date',
    array('date' => date('Y-m-d'))
);
```

Comment: PDO is 10 times faster is this situation !

Comment: @realtebo all cases in this question use PDO

Comment: Yes, it's just an entusiastic confirm from me :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
 $query = "delete from `user_login_hash` where `day`!='".(date('Y-m-d',time()))."'";
                        $query->queryAll($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use query builder

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->delete('user_login_hash', 'day !=' . date('Y-m-d'));
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder#sec-15